# Trimming the video captured by the iphone camera programmatically?

Tags: iphone, user-interface, camera, avfoundation

I need to capture video for 5 minutes using iphone and then trim the captured video and save it in binary data format. If any body has done it ever, please help me to do so.

like that image http://www.askdavetaylor.com/3-blog-pics/apple-iphone-video-editing-4.png

```
- (BOOL) startCameraControllerFromViewController: (UIViewController*) controller
usingDelegate: (id <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>)                     delegate {

    NSLog(@"Camera Working");


    if (([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:

      UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera] == NO)

    || (delegate == nil)

    || (controller == nil))

    return NO;

    cameraUI            = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    cameraUI.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeMovie, nil];
    cameraUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

    // Displays a control that allows the user to choose picture or

    // movie capture, if both are available: video and image capturing

    //cameraUI.mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];


    // Hides the controls for moving & scaling pictures, or for

    // trimming movies. To instead show the controls, use YES.
    cameraUI.videoMaximumDuration = 300; // 5x60 sec 
    cameraUI.allowsEditing = YES;
    cameraUI.delegate = delegate;

    [controller presentModalViewController: cameraUI animated: YES];

    return YES;

}
```

Comment: http://www.askdavetaylor.com/3-blog-pics/apple-iphone-video-editing-4.png

Comment: Please any body tell me about trimming http://www.askdavetaylor.com/3-blog-pics/apple-iphone-video-editing-4.png like given in the pic